# Multiple conditions with the same subject

Tags: reversed-conditional

My title is probably not correct, but please bear with me (and feel free to edit it).

Consider the following two sentences.

> The manager is your second point of escalation if you have not received a response from the cashier within six hours during business hours or they were not able to resolve your concern.

> The manager is your second point of escalation if you have not received a response from the cashier within six hours during business hours or if they were not able to resolve your concern.

Is "if" required to be present twice for the sentence to be grammatically correct? I am being told it does, but it feels to me that adding the second "if" in this situation is incorrect. The reason is because the sentence could then be read as:

> The manager is your second point of escalation if you have not received a response from the cashier within six hours during business hours. The manager is your second point of escalation if they were not able to resolve your concern.

At that point, who is "they"? It's supposed to be the cashier, but it seems more likely to be interpreted as the manager, even though that renders the sentence meaningless.

I tried several internet searches but I am not completely sure of the language to use to describe my question so I was not able to find much specific to this issue.

Comment: Break it down and simplify to see: *Contact the manager if: 1) you have not received a response from the cashier or 2) your concern was unresolved.* <-- props to the passive voice here.

Comment: Who told you the second *if* was required? It's not necessary, and as you say it may misdirect the reader, but if your teacher or editor tells you to do it with two ifs, then you'd better do that.

Comment: I am a native US English speaker who is in a corporate training for a new position that involves limited writing for an external audience. One of my trainers said I needed to "correct" my original sentence to the second example in a broader review of some work I did for it. It's not a matter of a style guide, as there isn't one. English is their second language, for what it's worth. They also said I should use periods in webpage form labels (like "Address"), which another trainer agreed with me was definitely wrong, so I'm not convinced they're the most reliable source for grammar corrections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repeated "if" is optional, and sounds unnatural to me. The two conditions are in a parallel relationship, and it's common to elide duplicate words like that.

Business people often think that more words make it more formal, which may be why your trainer thinks this is necessary. But some simplifications are so common that they don't detract from the formality, and this is one of them.

The only potential problem is that it may not be clear who "they" refers to, and that ambiguity exists in all 3 versions. That can be resolved with a few extra words.

> The manager is your second point of escalation if you have not received a response from the cashier within six hours during business hours, or you contacted the cashier and they were not able to resolve your concern.